# What's more precedent: a CSS class or a pseudo-class with a * selector?

Tags: css, gtk

Let's say I have these two CSS rules:

```
*:selected {
    background-color: @some_color;
}

.cell {
    background-color: @base_color;
}
```

In the case of finding an :selected element with the class `cell`, both rules apply, but then which one is precedent? Should the element end with `base_color` or with `some_color`?

(Note: I added the gtk tag as well, because I want to know if the GTK+CSS engine actually behaves in the same way that browsers do. If it differs, it is probably a bug.)

Comment: I would think whichever one is used in the immediate div tag. So like <div>// selected cell <div> // .cell </div></div> the .cell would be used

Comment: A comment about the GTK CSS engine: it _should_ behave in the same way that browser CSS does; any discrepancies should be reported as bugs to bugzilla.gnome.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both rules have the same specificity of `[ 0 0 1 0 ]`, so the order is determined by source order.

In this case, `.cell` is specified later in the stylesheet, so `@base_color` would be used.

By the way, the `*` selector has zero specificity.

- Read more about CSS
  specificity: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- Another good article to look
  at: [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), the level of specificity is the same.  Therefore the winning rule falls to the cascade and `.cell` will take precedence.  The documentation doesn't say it explicitly for some reason, but `*` does not add specificity (i.e. it does not count as an element name, apparently).

> *             {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,0,0 */